# C++ - error: 'sleep' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows

I started learning programming a few days ago, and today i tried writing a countdown program, but everytime i try to start a program i get error: 'sleep' was not declared in this scope. I searched everywhere for solution but i didn't find it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {

 for(int i=30; i>=0; i--)

    {
        sleep(1000)
        system("cls")
        cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `sleep` is os API and not C++ standard. If you are on linux, add `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: And if you are on MS-Windows it's `Sleep`

Comment: Are you running this code in Windows or Linux ?

Comment: i am on windows, and i have added <windows.h>, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: i changed it to Sleep and it works now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: A more portable way to sleep would be to use the standardized function [std::this_thread::sleep_for()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Answer (score 6):

Try this out:

```
this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```

Source:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 5):

[`sleep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) is a POSIX (e.g. Linux, macOS) function.

The Windows "sleep" function is [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep). Note the upper-case `S` in `Sleep`.

For a portable solution that is independent of OS then use [`this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead.

Comment: Posix sleep is in seconds. Windows Sleep is in milliseconds

Comment: You should add `std::this_thread::sleep_for` as the portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is **Windows**, then use `Sleep()` instead of `sleep()` function prototype is in `windows.h`.

If you are using **UNIX** use `nanosleep()` or `usleep()` and the header name `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: If you want to use `<unisted.h>` instead of `<windows.h>`.*

Put this line in top your code:

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

---

But in response of you cuestion you have to use `Sleep()` instead of `sleep()`, notice the uppercase of `Sleep()`.